# replace fixed number number by variable on c#

Tags: c#, variables, int

I'm a beginner c# developper and I have a weird problem 
when i code

> public new Image Image
>           {
>
> ```
>         get { return base.Image; }
>         set
>         {
>
>             int w = Width *8/10   ,    h = 80  ;
>
>             Bitmap b = new Bitmap(value);
>             Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(b, w  ,h);
>             base.Image = bm;
>             base.Text = w.ToString();
>
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

the image look good

> int h = Height *8/10

the image look blur !

Comment: I think there's more to this than you're showing us..

Answer (score 0):

I think `value` variable might is related to to `h` and `w` that you are not showed to us so this won't blur:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(value);
int w = 80 ,h = 80  ;
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(b, w  ,h);
base.Image = bm;
```

*this is only a guess!*

Comment: public new Image Image
        {

            get { return base.Image; }
            set
            {

                int w = Width *8/10   ,    h = 80  ;

                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(value);
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(b, w  ,h);
                base.Image = bm;
                base.Text = w.ToString();

                
            }
        }

Comment: in this case it's look good but when I modify h by height*8/10 the image become blur !!

Comment: @Abbesomar what is `height` var?

Comment: Height is the height of the control

Comment: h = Height *8/10 = 80 i can see it from base.text = h.tostring();

Comment: @Abbesomar excuse me;I don't have any more idea!

Comment: h = 80 ==> clear / h = Height *8/10 ==> blur ( the value of h = 80 )

Answer (score 0):

> h = 80

==> clear

> h = Height *8/10

==> blur
( the value of h = 80 I can see it on text  )